# SanDisk External SSD Running at Slow Speeds

Tags: ssd, performance, external-hard-drive, usb-3

I recently purchased a new external 1TB SSD from SanDisk (SDSSDE30-1T00-G25). However, I am having an issue with its speed as it is limited to USB-2 speed, which is around 40MB/s.

[image: speed on first laptop]

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. I tried other ports, specifically USB 3.1 Gen 2 and USB 4.
2. I also tried other cables, including USB-C to A and USB-C to C cables.
3. I attempted to flip the USB-C direction.
4. I tried other operating systems, specifically Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.10.

Unfortunately, none of these options have worked for me. However, when I tried the SSD on another laptop with a USB-C to A cable and a USB 3.1 Gen 1 port with Windows 10, I achieved full speed. In fact, the speed was even faster than the advertised speed of 550 MB/s.

[image: Speed on secound laptop]

Now I am trying to fix this issue on my laptop. What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Note:
I also tried the SSD on other laptops, but some of them achieved full speed while others were limited to USB-2 speed.

Comment: The second screenshot doesn't seem to add up. Firstly the numbers are too high for USB 3.1 Gen 1 and secondly I doubt SanDisk would silently upgrade their product to be nearly twice as fast as advertised

Comment: It [seems](https://forums.sandisk.com/t/extremely-slow/74994/28) like the included Type-C to Type-A adapter is sensitive to the position of the Type-C plug. Try to reverse it.

Comment: Sorry, the laptop is actually an ASUS X570, so the port is a 3.2 Gen 1. I'm not certain about the speed, but it could be related to the cache. I've performed the benchmark test multiple times to confirm.

Comment: I tried to reverse it, but it didn't work.

Comment: @JamesP The drive itself appears to be a [Gen 2](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/portable-drives/sandisk-usb-3-2-ssd#SDSSDE30-1T00-G25) device though.

Comment: @MohammadDiab So do you mean the laptop that *you are having problem with* is ASUS X570? Since you mentioned Ubuntu, can you add `lsusb -t` and/or `lsusb.py -ui` output? (Maybe also `lspci -k`.) Also, can you clarify whether you are using the exact same cable in the working and non-working cases? (By exact same I mean also the fact that whether an adapter is needed / involved in the two cases.)

Comment: @TomYan: The OP specifically mentioned the port on the laptop was USB 3.1 Gen 1, and it still doesn't explain why the SSD is performing so much better than the manufacturer's own claims

Comment: @TomYan No, this laptop is working fine. the laptop I have problem with is Asus M6501....
Yes, I use same cables, and both works fine on ASUS X570.